# Adding Coordinates to A Map created in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a map of California subdivided with counties:

```
CAL17 <- ca_base +
    theme_nothing() +
    geom_polygon(data = ca_county, fill = NA, color = "yellow") +
    geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = NA)
```

Now I am trying to add the coordinates.

Every time I try to add the coordinates the California map disappears and a single purple dot appears on an X and Y axis plot.

```
labs17 <- data.frame(lon17, lat17, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) +
    ggplot() +
    geom_point(data = labs17, aes(x = lon17, y = lat17), color = "White", size = 5) +
    geom_point(data = labs17, aes(x = lon17, y = lat17), color = "yellow", size = 4)

CAL17 +
    geom_point(data = labs17, aes(x = lon17, y = lat17), color = "black", size = 5) +
    geom_point(data = ca_df, aes(x = lon17, y = lat17), color = "purple", size = 2)
```

and I get the following error

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'group' not found
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! If you can provide some sample data or make a minimal example that would help. At a first glance, it's not clear what `labs17` is supposed to be (plot or data), you `+ ggplot()` to it which is not correct syntax in any case, but then try to use it as `data` argument in `geom_point`. Hard to say more without runnable code

Comment: Also, unless `lon17` and `lat17` are defined objects, just the first line `data.frame(lon17, lat17, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` will fail. And since you're not adding anything *to* `CAL17`, you're starting a new plot. Having the old plot disappear when you start a new plot is expected. I think you probably want something like `CAL17 + geom_point(data = labs17, aes(...), ...)` I'd advise finding a working example and starting from there. If you need additional help, please try to share a small reproducible example, sharing some sample data.

Comment: Sorry I have an updated version:  

I have two plots that are plotting fine on their own:

CAL17 <- ca_base + theme_nothing() + geom_polygon(data = ca_county, fill = NA, color = "yellow") + geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = NA)

and 

Pt17 <- ggplot() + geom_point(data = labs17, aes(x = lon17, y = lat17), color = "White", size = 5) + geom_point(data = labs17, aes(x = lon17, y = lat17), color = "yellow", size = 4)

labs17 is a dataframe with 2 columns, 1 for longitude & one for latitude:       
            lon17    lat17
1  -119.2232 34.28367
2  -119.1865 34.23879

Comment: Please **edit** your question with additional content, rather than append them as comments. Comments are hard to format & harder to read, which diminishes your chances of getting good help.

Comment: I was able to find the way to do it:

After I created the map of California 
CA17 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = ca_county, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), fill = "light grey", color = "yellow") + 
  coord_fixed(1.3)

labs <- data.frame(
  long = c(lon17),
  lat = c(lat17), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

CA17 + geom_point(data = labs, aes(x = long, y = lat), color = "black", size = 1) + geom_point(data = labs, aes(x = long, y = lat), color = "purple", size = 2)